# CUA doesn't work in magit status buffer

Tags: magit

The title is basically everything what I know. CUA keys just don't work in magit status buffer.

In older versions, it worked. Sometimes. Now it consistently just doesn't work.

Emacs 26.2.
Newest magit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @npostavs figured out elsewhere: [...] the problem is that diff hunks have a keymap text property, which is higher priority than `emulation-mode-map-alists`.  See [(elisp) Searching Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-Keymaps.html):

```
           (or (FIND-IN (get-char-property (point) 'keymap))
               (FIND-IN-ANY emulation-mode-map-alists)
               ...
```

See the [double post](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3912) for more information.